# Adobe Acrobat: Advanced drop down / list

Tags: pdf, javascript, adobe-acrobat

A client of mine needs a PDF made which has a list of store locations, there are *a lot* of store locations however.

Each store is split into several parts,

```
 Store code: BB01
 Store Name: Bob's Burgers
 State: California
 Region: Orange County
 Address: 1234 Orange Bob Lane
```

We would optimally like to have a sort of "drill down" using multiple combo boxes, example: Select "California" from the state box, the Region box then lights up and lists only the regions that falls under California. Then you choose a region, the Store Name box lights up. Choose a store name, and finally you get a list of addresses.

That's the ideal solution, but I would expect we would need to use advanced javascript and maybe even a database to get that to work correctly.

Are there any built-in solutions that would help out our users? Maybe having a search for results text box, by typing "bob's burgers orange county" you get the entry above. I am pretty familiar with Javascript, but I have spent the past 3 hours trying to get something usable out and I just don't know enough about Acrobat.

Other ideas appreciated.

Comment: I went with an HTML solution which output the solution to a PDF form field. Not ideal, but it works.